# The Xmx Parameter Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: java, parameters, ram

I've got a java program that gets quite RAM-hungry over time (for as yet undetermined reasons). So to prevent it going crazy with the page file, I run it with the parameter -Xmx1536m, so that Java will just crash once the program's taken up one and a half gig of RAM. Better that then having my whole computer lock up.

The trouble is, it's not working. When I check Task Manager, sometimes Java is hogging 2.8GB of RAM, or higher! The program should be crashing well before it gets to that point!

Why isn't it?

Comment: `-Xmx` only controls the size of the Java _heap_. Lots of things aren't in the heap: code (native, bytecode/classfiles and JIT); thread stacks; NIO buffers; data allocated by native code.

Comment: Okay. So how do I limit the amount of RAM that the program uses?